# How to write acceptance tests easily in Codeception to test a Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, tdd, codeception

I am learning to write a Wordpress plugin and am trying to test it using [Codeception/WP-Browser](https://codeception.com/for/wordpress). I want to write **acceptance tests** to test the behavior of the plugin when it is activated. The acceptance test runs with Selenium Webriver/ChromeDriver

Nevertheless, there is some behavior that I don't know how to test. The "happy path" test are in green, but the failure cases are in red because the plugin is activated successfully.

How could I make the failure tests turn to green?

---

### What should happen

If the user activates the plugin, a class will check

- the PHP version on the server
- the Wordpress version

and if they are not compatible with the plugin, it will show an **error page** to the user call [wp_die](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_die/).

### What happens now

The **happy path test passes, but not the failure cases**.

The problem is that, because in the acceptance tests I don't have access to server side code, I don't know how I could change the **behavior of the plugin during the activation to test it in case of failure**.

This learning project is structured in this fashion:

```
testwidget
  |
  +-----tests
  |       +---acceptance
  |               +----activationCest.php
  +-----src
  |       +---activation
  |               +----activation.php
  +-------widget-plugin.php
```

This is my code:

**./widget-plugin.php**

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: testwidget
 * Description: a test of developing a Post of the Day widget
 * Author: Rafael
 * Text Domain: testwidget
 */
namespace Testwidget;

require __DIR__ . '\vendor\autoload.php';

// to avoid exposing information if the plugin is called directly
if (function_exists('add_action') === false) {
    echo 'I am a plugin. I cannot be called directly';
    exit();
}

register_activation_hook(
    __FILE__,
    function () {
        $wpVersion = get_bloginfo('version');

        $act = new Activation(PHP_VERSION, $wpVersion);
        $act->checkEnvironment();
    }
);
```

I think the problem is here: I don't know **how to change, from the test file, the behavior of the function that [register_activation_hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_activation_hook/) will call**.

The second parameter of `register_activation_hook` is a function with no parameters, according to the official documentation.

In that function, I pass some parameters to the Activation constructor to make it unit-testable (no problems in the unit tests).

This is the test file:

**./tests/acceptance/activationCest.php**

```php
<?php 

class activationCest
{
    public function _before(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        // to reset the state of the plugin after each test
        try {
            $I->loginAsAdmin();
            $I->amOnPluginsPage();
            $I->seePluginDeactivated('testwidget');
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            $I->deactivatePlugin('testwidget');
        }
    }

    public function _after(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
    }

    // tests
    public function activationCaseFailPHP(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo('see an error message if the PHP version 
            is not compatible with the plugin');

        $I->loginAsAdmin();
        $I->amOnPluginsPage();
        $I->activatePlugin('testwidget');

        $I->see(
            '<h2>Your PHP version is outdated</h2>
                <p>Testwidget requires a PHP version equal or superior to 7.0.</p>
                <p>Contact your hosting provider to update PHP</p>'
        );
    }

    public function activationCaseFailWP(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo('see an error message if the Wordpress version
            is not compatible with the plugin');

        $I->loginAsAdmin();
        $I->amOnPluginsPage();
        $I->activatePlugin('testwidget');

        $I->see(
            '<h2>Your Wordpress version is outdated</h2>
                <p>Testwidget requires a PHP version equal or superior to 5.0.</p>
                <p>Contact your hosting provider to update Wordpress</p>'
        );
    }

    public function activationCaseFailPHPAndWP(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo('see an error message if the PHP and Wordpress
            versions are not compatible with the plugin');

        $I->loginAsAdmin();
        $I->amOnPluginsPage();
        $I->activatePlugin('testwidget');

        $I->see(
            '<h2>Your PHP and Wordpress versions are outdated</h2>
                <p>Testwidget requires 
                <ul>
                    <li>a PHP version equal or superior to 7.0 and</li>
                    <li>a Wordpress version equal or superior to 5.0.</li>
                </ul>
                <p>Contact your hosting provider to update PHP and Wordpress</p>'
        );
    }

    public function activationCaseSuccess(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo('see a success message if the PHP and Wordpress versions
            are compatible with the plugin');

        // setup
        $I->loginAsAdmin();
```

Although it might be unnecessary, I include here the code of the Activation class just to be thorough:

**./src/activation/activation.php**

```php
<?php
namespace Testwidget;

/**
 * checks the environment of the plugin allows it to be
 * activated correctly. If that is not the case, it will
 * show an error message
 * 
 */
class Activation
{
    private $phpVersion;
    private $wpVersion;

    private const PHP_LOWEST_VERSION = '7.0';
    private const WP_LOWEST_VERSION = '5.0';

    public function __construct($phpVersion, $wpVersion)
    {
        $this->phpVersion = $phpVersion;
        $this->wpVersion = $wpVersion;
    }

    /**
     * predicate that returns true if the PHP version 
     * running on the server is superior to the minimal 
     * version the plugin requires; otherwise, false
     * 
     * @return boolean
     * 
     * @see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php
     */
    private function comparePhpVersions()
    {
        return version_compare($this->phpVersion, self::PHP_LOWEST_VERSION, '>=');
    }

    /**
     * predicate that returns true if the Wordpress version 
     * running on the server is superior to the minimal 
     * version the plugin requires; otherwise, false
     *
     * @return boolean
     * 
     * @see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php
     */
    private function compareWpVersions()
    {
        return version_compare($this->wpVersion, self::WP_LOWEST_VERSION, '>=');
    }       

    /**
     * If the PHP and Wordpress versions aren't compatible with the plugin,
     * the method shows an error message.
     */
    public function checkEnvironment()
    {
        // Array with cases and conditions to evaluate the environment
        $conditions = [
            'phpAndWp' => function () {
                return $this->comparePhpVersions() === false &&
                    $this->compareWpVersions() === false;
            },
            'php' => function () {
                return $this->comparePhpVersions() === false;
            },
            'wp' => function () {
                return $this->compareWpVersions() === false;
            }
        ];

        // array with cases and error messages
        $errors = [
            'phpAndWp' => '<h2>Your PHP and Wordpress versions are outdated</h2>
                <p>Testwidget requires 
                <ul>
                    <li>a PHP version equal or superior to 7.0 and</li>
                    <li>a Wordpress version equal or superior to 5.0.</li>
                </ul>
                <p>Contact your hosting provider to update PHP and Wordpress</p>',
            'php' => '<h2>Your PHP version is outdated</h2>
                <p>Testwidget requires a PHP version equal or superior to 7.0.</p>
                <p>Contact your hosting provider to update PHP</p>',
            'wp' => '<h2>Your Wordpress version is outdated</h2>
                <p>Testwidget requires a PHP version equal or superior to 5.0.</p>
                <p>Contact your hosting provider to update Wordpress</p>'
        ];

        foreach(array_keys($conditions) as $case) {
            if ($conditions[$case]()) {
                wp_die($errors[$case]);
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Just now, the **only test that passes is the success case**. The tests of the failure cases are in red because the plugin is activated successfully.

I don't see clearly how to acceptance test the behavior of my class in case of failure.

How would you solve this problem? Would you change the file structure to make the code more easily testable?

Comment: I think that the best place to ask this question is https://github.com/lucatume/wp-browser/issues/ because @lucatume hadn't logged-in to StackOverflow since 2015.

Comment: You might be right. Thank you for your orientation.